# Why dotenv files should not be checked in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

I'm new to *nodejs*, so forgive me if my question is too trivial. 
I'm creating an *enviornment* files using *dotenv*.

However, on their [WebSite](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv), they recommend against checking in *.env* file. 
So, I was wondering if this files is not checked in , how will I tell the other developers about the *environment* variables that the application needs. They would require to fill out the *values* of environment variables because it could be used in all the places in the *js* (sever, config) files. 
And it would be non-trivial to look at every files that uses env variables and replace? Unless I'm missing something entirely.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: that's what `readme.md` files are for ... instructions

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks. Okay, so for production, one has to look at readme.md files and replace all the env variables with production values everywhere in the file. (Since dotenv is development purpose only)?

Comment: @ZammyPage No; The entire purpose of environment variables is to not have to replace anything throughout the code. You either add an `.env` file (which is read by `dotenv`) or you just set the environment variables directly in your system.

Comment: @JaromandaX README files are fine for documenting the environment variables, but having a sample file makes everyone's life easier.

Comment: yes, but you would describe what it's for in ... oh, the readme :p

Comment: I think I get it now. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Environment variables are typically used for environment-specific configuration values, like database credentials, API endpoints, and so on. Since they're environment-specific, and usually hold sensitive data like database credentials, `.env` files should not be committed.

If you want to show which environment variables are used, one method is to create and commit a sample file:

`.env.sample`

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_DATABASE=our_project
```

Then it's up to the other developers to copy the same and create their own `.env` file (or just populate the relevant environment variables on their system).

Comment: I'm just trying to understand if that is the standard approach? I know I can do that? But is that really a standard appraoch?

Comment: @ZammyPage Yep, it's a standard approach. You tagged Laravel, which does the same thing out of the box: `In a fresh Laravel installation, the root directory of your application will contain a .env.example file.` https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#environment-configuration

Comment: by this question what i have got we don't commit the .env file to version control but in the production environment we need this .env file and have to create our own due to its sensitivity right   @ZammyPage ?