# I dont quite get the concept of environment variables in git

Tags: git, npm

Need guidance. In our git we have 2 branches(develop and master). develop is for my development environment while master is for my prod environment(my dev and prd environment have different url). My question is how do you handle different url in your .env file when switching branches if your .env file is in your .gitignore.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60990940/i-want-one-file-to-be-different-between-two-branches-but-rest-all-files-must-be#comment107917689_60990940) on this question: [I want one file to be different between two branches, but rest all files must be in sync, How do I manage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60990940/i-want-one-file-to-be-different-between-two-branches-but-rest-all-files-must-be)

> There's no such thing as a branch-specific file in Git because branch
>   names move and change, while commits don't, and any one given commit
>   can be on many branches, or no branches at all, and this situation can
>   change from one moment to the next.

You can commit a `.env.dev` and a `.env.prod` and copy the one that you need into the ignored `.env`.

Or use [dotenv-flow](https://github.com/kerimdzhanov/dotenv-flow) or [custom-env](https://github.com/erisanolasheni/custom-env).

Although the [dotenv FAQ](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#faq) recommends against committing and having multiple `.env` files (also [Why dotenv files should not be checked in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014558/why-dotenv-files-should-not-be-checked-in)). In that case you can do [this](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/220#issuecomment-323207844).

Comment: I tried a different approach. I tried using "git-branch-is" to check what branch I am in and based on that branch I am currently using that dictates what variable I should use